# `clflush` of large memory area doesn't flush?

Tags: c, performance, assembly, caching, x86

I want to try to measure timing differences of memory accesses, when accessed from the cache and when accessed from the main memory.

Consider this program:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <time.h>

#include <x86intrin.h>

#define CL_SIZE 64
#define REGION_SIZE 0x40000000  //A 1Gb memory region

void gen_perm(int* arr_ptr,int N)
/** This function generates a random permutation of integers**/
{
  srand(time(NULL));
  for (int i=0;i<N;i++)
    arr_ptr[i] = i;

  for(int i=N-1;i>=0;i--)
  {
    int index = rand() % (i+1);
    int temp = arr_ptr[i];
    arr_ptr[i] = arr_ptr[index];
    arr_ptr[index] = temp;
  }
}

inline void force_read(char* address) 
/** We force a memory read of a given memory address **/
{
   asm  volatile (""::"r"(*address):"memory");
}

inline uint64_t timing()
/* This function gives us a timestamp, useful for measuring clock cycles */
{
  uint32_t time_lo, time_hi;
  asm volatile(
    "mfence \n"
    "rdtscp \n"
    "mov %%edx, %[hi]\n"
    "mov %%eax, %[lo]\n"
    : [hi] "=r" (time_hi), [lo] "=r" (time_lo)
    :
    : "rdx", "rax", "rcx");
  return ( time_lo | ((uint64_t)time_hi << 32) );
}

char* mapped_area;

void clean_cache()
/**Objective is to flush the mapped_area completely from the cache
 * */
{
  for (int i=0;i<512*100;i+=CL_SIZE) // ---> NOTE THE !!! 512*100 !!! I'm not even flushing the entire mapped_area
    asm volatile ("clflush %[target]"::[target]"m"(mapped_area[i]));
    //_mm_clflush(&mapped_area[i]);  ---> You can use this intrinsic function too

}

int profile(int stride,int range)
{
  uint64_t* result_array = malloc(range*sizeof(uint64_t));
  int* perm_array = malloc(range*sizeof(int));

  gen_perm(perm_array,range);
  clean_cache();

  for(int i = 0; i < range; i++)
  {
    int mixed_index = perm_array[i]; //Trying to remove the prefetcher influence
    uint64_t time[2];

    time[0] = timing();
    force_read(&mapped_area[mixed_index*stride]);
    time[1] = timing();

    result_array[mixed_index] = time[1]-time[0];
  }

  printf("\nLineNo\tTime");
  for(int i=0; i< range; i++)
    printf("\n%d\t%lu",i,result_array[i]);

  free(perm_array);
  free(result_array);
}

int main()
{
  mapped_area = memalign(4096,REGION_SIZE);
  profile(512, 100);
  free(mapped_area);
  return 0;
}
```

The output I get is:

```
LineNo  Time
0   76
1   76
2   76
3   76
4   692
5   76
6   76
7   76
8   280
9   76
10  76
11  76
12  76

....

97  76
98  76
99  76
```

Clearly, this value is way too less to be correct (it should be around 200-300 I think), if I'm actually fetching the value from memory. Where could I be going wrong?

Comment: I have a strong suspicion that this behaviour is due to malloc doing some kind of lazy mapping, where I need to actually access the page to get memory allocated

Comment: @Ext3h Not true, `clflush` invalidates a line. It is actually used on flush+reload attacks. Something else must get in the way here, possibly the OS zeroing the pages. I didn't read the code, though.

Comment: @Ext3h I thought that coherency was something **guaranteed by** the processor (I would be very, very surpised if programmers use `clflush` to actually restore coherency)... Anyway, my point is that the reads from the array don't seem to be coming from main memory. I also use a `mfence` in my timing function to make all memory instructions globally visible.

Comment: @MargaretBloom I have a strong suspicion about OS involvement too. I will try to write something into all the pages, so that the pages are 'really' owned by the process, and then hopefully, we should have some better results

Comment: @SuraajKS Yes, that's a good idea. Touch every page to force the OS to commit it in memory. You are using reference cycles and not core clock cycles but as long as the core clock doesn't ramp up or down to much that wouldn't matter a lot.

Comment: Given how tight the test loop is, can you actually rule out prefetch by speculative execution? Maybe you could work around that by introducing a data to address dependency between loop iterations, and then count total execution time instead?

Comment: @MargaretBloom So `rdtscp` uses gives us 'reference cycle' count? I thought that it measured the number of 'ticks' of the processor core. Always good to learn more :)

Comment: @Ext3h I use a stride, as well as a random access pattern. This should hopefully eliminate the prefetchers (stream as well as stride). `rdtscp` is also an instruction that flushes the ROB, and in combination with `mfence`, out of order execution shouldn't be too much of a problem in our code loop (I don't even have stores, so the `mfence` shouldn't even be necessary!)

Comment: That's expected to eliminate simple prefetch, but not enough to prevent speculative execution within the out-of-order window, is it? ***Processors are free to fetch and cache data speculatively from regions of system memory that use the WB, WC, and WT memory types. This speculative fetching can occur at any time and is not tied to instruction execution. Thus, it is not ordered with respect to executions of the MFENCE instruction; data can be brought into the caches speculatively just before, during, or after the execution of an MFENCE instruction.***

Comment: @Ext3h Okay.. but `rdtscp` is serializing (kinda) too. Basically, if I have a `rdtscp; load (some random load) ; rdtscp` in my compiled code, I can rest assured that I will time the load latency (I believe). You can take a look at the assembly output of my code

Comment: Documentation for `rdtscp` also states ***The RDTSCP instruction is not a serializing instruction, but it does wait until all previous instructions have executed [...] subsequent instructions may begin execution before the read operation is performed.*** So no, you can only tell when the instruction have completed, but not when execution had begun.

Comment: @Ext3h exactly... So the second `rdtscp` will give me timestamp of load *completion* (it should be 'retirement' technically) , while the first one will do so for all instructions before the  load. I can then time the load. Btw,  are you confusing speculative execution with out-of-order execution?

Comment: What CPU did you test on?  Benchmark results are much more useful when the hardware is known.  (e.g. you used `mfence` for some reason ahead of `rdtscp`.  It's basically serializing on Skylake, preventing all later instructions from even issuing, but it's faster on some earlier CPUs.)  Also the OS type and version.  Linux?

Comment: @PeterCordes, I have tested on my Intel i7-4720HQ processor (Haswell), and my machine runs Linux kernel 5.4.52. In my case, I don't absolutely need to use `mfence`, because the `rdtscp` acts as a serializing instruction for loads (it flushes the ROB, and later instructions can't 'issue' **into ROB** from backend until `rdtscp` retires/commits?) Btw, do you have an idea why the `rdtscp` instruction doesn't measure the page_fault latency?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the code is correct (to the best of my knowledge). I think that the problem arises due to the involvement of the operating system, which cleverly **page_faults and returns 0** whenever I try to read something from `mapped_area`. This is easily mitigated by forcing the OS to give us pages by writing into them.

```
int main()
{
  mapped_area = memalign(4096,REGION_SIZE);
  for(int i = 0;i<REGION_SIZE;i+=4096)  mapped_area[i] = 123; //4096 is the page size. I should probably replace by a standard macro
  profile(512, 100);
  free(mapped_area);
  return 0;
}
```

This gives me:

```
LineNo  Time
0   272
1   266
2   422
3   234
4   234
5   254
6   220
7   230
8   266
...

97  212
98  264
99  268
```

Pretty consistent!

P.S: I'm not sure why the time reading didn't increase even though we have a page fault... Any ideas?